# Al ejecutar la acción de guardar, no adiciona el la BD en Java Web con primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces, crud

Comencé el aprendizaje de JavaWeb con el framework primefaces, generé un CRUD de una Base de Datos y todo salió perfecto, la BD se encuentra exactamente como debe estar.

El primer problema consiste en que a la hora de adicionar en la tabla paciente, uno de los campos se llama **registro**, el mismo deseo que se genere automticamente al cargar el formulario, esto lo hago con un Bean llamado pacienteBean que genera el número con un formato determindo y lo pone en el input, **Ej:202102-001**, el cual seria un consecutivo.

Hasta ahi todo bien, una vez llenado el formulario al dar `Salvar`, muestra un mensaje satisfactorio pero por la consola sale el siguiente error:

> Información:   EditViolation: ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='no puede ser null', propertyPath=registro, rootBeanClass=class sicklemia.Entities.Paciente, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}.

El Bean esta definido de la siguiente forma:

```
@Named(value = "pacienteBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PacienteBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of PacienteBean
     */

    @EJB
    private PacienteFacade pFacade;
    private String registro;

    public PacienteBean() {
    }

    public String getRegistro() {
        return pFacade.getNumber();
    }

    public void setRegistro(String registro) {
        this.registro = pFacade.getNumber();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        registro = pFacade.getNumber();
    }
}
```

El objeto **pFacade** es quien se encarga de buscar y generar el numero consecutivo correspondiente.

El input en el formulario se encuentra de la siguiente forma:

```
<p:inputText id="registro" value="#{pacienteBean.registro}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_registro}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreatePacienteRequiredMessage_registro}"/>
```

[image: Formulario Nuevo Paciente]

Mi segunda duda es la siguiente, tengo una tabla registro relacionada con la tabla paciente, o sea un paciente puede tener varios registros, los registros tienen como llave foránea el **id** del paciente, quisiera que al agregar un Nuevo Paciente poder almacenar algunos datos en la tabla registro, desde el mismo formulario. Utilizo NetBeans 8.2 y server GlassFish Server 4.1.1. Espero puedan ayudarme o mostrarme algun ejemplo.

[image: Formulario Nuevo Registro]

```
package sicklemia.Entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author femorell
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "paciente")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findByRegistro", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.registro = :registro")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findByCi", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.ci = :ci")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findByNombre", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.nombre = :nombre")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findByApellido1", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.apellido1 = :apellido1")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findByApellido2", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.apellido2 = :apellido2")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findByTelefono", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.telefono = :telefono")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findByDireccion", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.direccion = :direccion")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findByAnalisis", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.analisis = :analisis")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Paciente.findBySoltera", query = "SELECT p FROM Paciente p WHERE p.soltera = :soltera")})
public class Paciente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "registro")
    private String registro;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "ci")
    private String ci;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "apellido_1")
    private String apellido1;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "apellido_2")
    private String apellido2;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "telefono")
    private String telefono;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "analisis")
    private boolean analisis;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "soltera")
    private boolean soltera;
    @JoinColumn(name = "area_salud", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private AreaSalud areaSalud;
    @JoinColumn(name = "genotipo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Genotipo genotipoId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "municipio_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Municipio municipioId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "provincia_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Provincia provinciaId;

    public Paciente() {
    }

    public Paciente(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Paciente(Integer id, String registro, String ci, String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, boolean analisis, boolean soltera) {
        this.id = id;
        this.registro = registro;
        this.ci = ci;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
        this.analisis = analisis;
        this.soltera = soltera;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRegistro() {
        return registro;
    }

    public void setRegistro(String registro) {
        this.registro = registro;
    }

    public String getCi() {
        return ci;
    }

    public void setCi(String ci) {
        this.ci = ci;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido1() {
        return apellido1;
    }

    public void setApellido1(String apellido1) {
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    }

    public String getApellido2() {
        return apellido2;
    }

    public void setApellido2(String apellido2) {
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public boolean getAnalisis() {
        return analisis;
    }

    public void setAnalisis(boolean analisis) {
        this.analisis = analisis;
    }

    public boolean getSoltera() {
        return soltera;
    }

    public void setSoltera(boolean soltera) {
        this.soltera = soltera;
    }

    public AreaSalud getAreaSalud() {
        return areaSalud;
    }

    public void setAreaSalud(AreaSalud areaSalud) {
        this.areaSalud = areaSalud;
    }

    public Genotipo getGenotipoId() {
        return genotipoId;
    }

    public void setGenotipoId(Genotipo genotipoId) {
        this.genotipoId = genotipoId;
    }

    public Municipio getMunicipioId() {
        return municipioId;
    }

    public void setMunicipioId(Municipio municipioId) {
        this.municipioId = municipioId;
    }

    public Provincia getProvinciaId() {
        return provinciaId;
    }

    public void setProvinciaId(Provincia provinciaId) {
        this.provinciaId = provinciaId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Paciente)) {
            return false;
        }
        Paciente other = (Paciente) object;
        return !((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id)));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "sicklemia.Entities.Paciente[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
    
}

<h:panelGroup id="display">
       <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{pacienteController.selected != null}">  
            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_registro}" for="registro" />
               <p:inputText id="registro" value="#{pacienteBean.registro}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_registro}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreatePacienteRequiredMessage_registro}"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_ci}" for="ci" />
                                    <p:inputText id="ci" value="#{pacienteController.selected.ci}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_ci}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreatePacienteRequiredMessage_ci}"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_nombre}" for="nombre" />
                                    <p:inputText id="nombre" value="#{pacienteController.selected.nombre}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_nombre}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreatePacienteRequiredMessage_nombre}"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_apellido1}" for="apellido1" />
                                    <p:inputText id="apellido1" value="#{pacienteController.selected.apellido1}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_apellido1}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreatePacienteRequiredMessage_apellido1}"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_apellido2}" for="apellido2" />
                                    <p:inputText id="apellido2" value="#{pacienteController.selected.apellido2}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_apellido2}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreatePacienteRequiredMessage_apellido2}"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_telefono}" for="telefono" />
                                    <p:inputText id="telefono" value="#{pacienteController.selected.telefono}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_telefono}" />
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_direccion}" for="direccion" />
                                    <p:inputText id="direccion" value="#{pacienteController.selected.direccion}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_direccion}" />
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_analisis}" for="analisis" />
                                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="analisis" value="#{pacienteController.selected.analisis}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPacienteRequiredMessage_analisis}"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_soltera}" for="soltera" />
                                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="soltera" value="#{pacienteController.selected.soltera}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPacienteRequiredMessage_soltera}"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_areaSalud}" for="areaSalud" />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="areaSalud" value="#{pacienteController.selected.areaSalud}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPacienteRequiredMessage_areaSalud}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{areaSaludController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                                       var="areaSaludItem"
                                                       itemValue="#{areaSaludItem}"/>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_genotipoId}" for="genotipoId" />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="genotipoId" value="#{pacienteController.selected.genotipoId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPacienteRequiredMessage_genotipoId}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{genotipoController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                                       var="genotipoIdItem"
                                                       itemValue="#{genotipoIdItem}"/>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_municipioId}" for="municipioId" />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="municipioId" value="#{pacienteController.selected.municipioId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPacienteRequiredMessage_municipioId}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{municipioController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                                       var="municipioIdItem"
                                                       itemValue="#{municipioIdItem}"/>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePacienteLabel_provinciaId}" for="provinciaId" />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="provinciaId" value="#{pacienteController.selected.provinciaId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPacienteRequiredMessage_provinciaId}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{provinciaController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                                       var="provinciaIdItem"
                                                       itemValue="#{provinciaIdItem}"/>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{pacienteController.create}" value="#{bundle.Save}" update="display,:PacienteListForm:datalist,:growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(args,'PacienteCreateDialog');"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Cancel}" onclick="PacienteCreateDialog.hide()" immediate="true"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**Este es el PacienteController **

```
package sicklemia.Controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Named;
import sicklemia.Entities.Paciente;
import sicklemia.JsfUtil.JsfUtil;
import sicklemia.JsfUtil.JsfUtil.PersistAction;

@Named("pacienteController")
@SessionScoped
public class PacienteController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private sicklemia.Controller.PacienteFacade ejbFacade;
    private List<Paciente> items = null;
    private Paciente selected;

    public PacienteController() {
    }
    
    public Paciente getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Paciente selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    protected void setEmbeddableKeys() {
    }

    protected void initializeEmbeddableKey() {
    }

    private PacienteFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public Paciente prepareCreate() {
        selected = new Paciente();
        initializeEmbeddableKey();
        return selected;
    }

    public void create() {
        persist(PersistAction.CREATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PacienteCreated"));
        if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
            items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        persist(PersistAction.UPDATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PacienteUpdated"));
    }

    public void destroy() {
        persist(PersistAction.DELETE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PacienteDeleted"));
        if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
            selected = null; // Remove selection
            items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
        }
    }

    public List<Paciente> getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = getFacade().findAll();
        }
        return items;
    }

    private void persist(PersistAction persistAction, String successMessage) {
        if (selected != null) {
            setEmbeddableKeys();
            try {
                if (persistAction != PersistAction.DELETE) {
                    getFacade().edit(selected);
                } else {
                    getFacade().remove(selected);
                }
                JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(successMessage);
            } catch (EJBException ex) {
                String msg = "";
                Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
                if (cause != null) {
                    msg = cause.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
                if (msg.length() > 0) {
                    JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(msg);
                } else {
                    JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Paciente getPaciente(java.lang.Integer id) {
        return getFacade().find(id);
    }

    public List<Paciente> getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
        return getFacade().findAll();
    }

    public List<Paciente> getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
        return getFacade().findAll();
    }

    @FacesConverter(forClass = Paciente.class)
    public static class PacienteControllerConverter implements Converter {

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            PacienteController controller = (PacienteController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "pacienteController");
            return controller.getPaciente(getKey(value));
        }

        java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
            java.lang.Integer key;
            key = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return key;
        }

        String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(value);
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof Paciente) {
                Paciente o = (Paciente) object;
                return getStringKey(o.getId());
            } else {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "object {0} is of type {1}; expected type: {2}", new Object[]{object, object.getClass().getName(), Paciente.class.getName()});
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Clase PacienteFacade**

```
package sicklemia.Controller;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import sicklemia.Entities.Paciente;

/**
 *
 * @author femorell
 */
@Stateless
public class PacienteFacade extends AbstractFacade<Paciente> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CPGMPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public PacienteFacade() {
        super(Paciente.class);
    }
   
     public String getNumber() {
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Number.findAll", sicklemia.Entities.Number.class);
        List<sicklemia.Entities.Number> lastNumber = q.getResultList();
        String next = "";
        String datep = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
        String[] parm = datep.split("-");
        String ap = parm[0].trim();
        String mp = parm[1].trim();

        if (!lastNumber.isEmpty()) {
            String select = lastNumber.get(lastNumber.size() - 1).getConsecutivo();
            if (!select.trim().isEmpty()) {
                String cns = "";
                String[] sp = select.split("-");
                String as = sp[0].substring(0, 3);
                String ms = sp[0].substring(4, 5);
                int n = Integer.parseInt(sp[1]);
                if (ap.equalsIgnoreCase(as) && mp.equalsIgnoreCase(ms)) {
                    if (n + 1 < 10) {
                        cns = "00".concat(String.valueOf(n + 1));
                    } else if (n + 1 > 9 && n + 1 < 100) {
                        cns = "0".concat(String.valueOf(n + 1));
                    } else {
                        cns = String.valueOf(n + 1);
                    }
                    next = ap + mp + "-" + cns;
                } else if (ap.equalsIgnoreCase(as) && !mp.equalsIgnoreCase(ms)) {
                    if (n + 1 < 10) {
                        cns = "00".concat(String.valueOf(n + 1));
                    } else if (n + 1 > 9 && n + 1 < 100) {
                        cns = "0".concat(String.valueOf(n + 1));
                    } else {
                        cns = String.valueOf(n + 1);
                    }
                    next = ap + mp + "-" + cns;
                } else if (!ap.equalsIgnoreCase(as) && !mp.equalsIgnoreCase(ms)) {
                    if (n + 1 < 10) {
                        cns = "00".concat(String.valueOf(n + 1));
                    } else if (n + 1 > 9 && n + 1 < 100) {
                        cns = "0".concat(String.valueOf(n + 1));
                    } else {
                        cns = String.valueOf(n + 1);
                    }
                    next = ap + mp + "-" + cns;
                }
            } else {
                next = ap + mp + "-" + "001";
            }
            return next;
        }
        return next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Podrías poner tu entity?  El problema  es que algúin otro campo del entity  tiene  una restricción de no nulo.Aunque el mensaje se refiere a "registro".  Deberias poner el codigo donde guardas o haces el save. Dado que en tu Bean haces referencia un string del mismo bean y no al  del entity.

Comment: Buenas, ya agregue la Entity, en la misma el campo dice que no puede ser nulo, tambien agregue el formulario completo, porque creo que es a la hora se establecer el campo registro en el paciente selected.

Comment: Si lo desea pudo enviarle el proyecto, y la bd

Comment: Si te fijas todo tu formulario hace referencia a los campos del entity  menos el campo registro que es el del bean. La verdad que no deberías utilizar paci3nteBean. Lo que deberías hacer es una de dos: inicializar en el controlador current.registro=ejbFacade.getNumber() antes de presentar el formulario o bien el constructor que no tiene argumentos inicializas registro=ejbFacade.GetNumber();  enl el formulario utiliza selected.registro.

Comment: Si pones el controlador PacienteController te muestro como hacerlo

Comment: ¿una duda? Por qué ni generas el número justo antes de guardar el registro en la base de datos y lo muestras junto al mensaje satisfactorio? ¿El número es clave única?

Comment: El número no es clave única, es un consecutivo del paciente que ingresa al sistema, generado a partir del anterior, pero estoy valorando usarlo como llave primaria porque de igual forma tengo que usarlo en la tabla registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema  que tienes es  que estás utilizando en el formulario un campo perteneciente a un Bean y no al entity. Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

En PacienteController:

```
 // Generalmente prepareCreate se invoca desde un action para cargar el formulario de creación y debería se así:

public String prepareCreate() {
       selected = new Paciente();
       initializeEmbeddableKey();
       //  En este punto haces lo que hacias en el bean. Le asignas el numero sólo cuando se va a crear el registro. 
       selected.registro  = ejbFacade.getNumber();
       return "CreatedPaciente"; //Este es el nombre de la pagina o el outcome del formulario

   }
```

En algún lado de tu menu de opciones debes tener:

```
  <p:commandLink 
      value="Crear Paciente"
      action="#{pacienteController.prepareCreate}"
     ...
  </p:commandLink>
```

o en un menuItem_

```
<p:menuItem value="Crear Paciente"
            action="#{pacienteController.prepareCreate}"

 ...
</p:menuItem>
```

En el formulario el inputtext lo haces disabled porque es un dato que se autogenera y no lo ingresa el usuario:

```
 <p:inputText id="registro" value="#{pacienteController.selected.registro}" title="#{bundle.CreatePacienteTitle_registro}" disabled="true"/>
```

Olvidate de PacienteBean. Con los cambios de arriba deberia funcionar y guardar el registro correctamente.

Comment: Funciono perfectamente, lo que me di cuenta de qie no hay que llamar al action="#{pacienteController.prepareCreate}", sino al action="#{pacienteController.create}". La otra duda es como logar insertar algunos campos de otra entity de conjunto con ese mismo formulario como ya habia puesto en la descripcion de la pregunta al inicio. De todas formas mil gracias hermano.

Comment: Tienes que  crear la relación en el entity Paciente y en el  entity Registro para que puedas de un solo save grabar ambas tablas. SI consideras que fue solución aceptala o pon tu solución para que la pregunta no quede en nada.

Comment: Listo, **aceptada** y de **mucha utilidad**. Ya la relación esta creada, como quedaria la llamada del action en el  '<p:commandLink 
      value="Crear Paciente"
      action="#{pacienteController.prepareCreate}"
     ...
  </p:commandLink>' para las dos entities al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Lo que entiendo  es que quieres que cuando se guarde  el entity Paciente tambien se  guarden  datos en otra  tabla simultaneamente. ¿cierto? En el entity Paciente no he visto la relación con esa otra tabla.  Si es así, extiendo la respuesta pero deberías poner el entity "Registro". En todo caso pasamos  la coordinación al chat.

Comment: Es tal y como usted lo entendio, pero la tabla Registro es la que guarda el id del paciente, de esa forma un Paciente puede tener varios Registros. Pero solo deseo persistir algunos campos no todos,